# How do I return the angle of orientation from getOrientation() and Open CV code?

Tags: python, opencv, orientation

I am trying to find the angle of orientation of an object in an image. In the image output, the image contains the axis and degree of rotation, and I want to have that degree of location so I can write out that data to a `.csv`. In other words, I need to output the value of the angle rather than just the annotation on the image. I attached the picture of my output and below is the section of data to do with the orientation.

I am using the OpenCV package.

```
for i, c in enumerate(contours):

  # Calculate the area of each contour
  area = cv.contourArea(c)

  # Ignore contours that are too small or too large
  if area < 3700 or 100000 < area:
    continue

  # Draw each contour only for visualisation purposes
  cv.drawContours(img, contours, i, (0, 0, 255), 2)

  # Find the orientation of each shape
  getOrientation(c, img)
```

Sample output image:

[image: sample output image]

Comment: Return the angle to what?

Comment: getOrientation () comes from what software?

Comment: I just made some changes

Comment: I don't understand your question... According to the sample image, it looks like you can use the [Fitting a Line](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) example (for each contour), something like `vx, vy, cx, cy = cv2.fitLine(c, cv2.DIST_L2, 0, 0.01, 0.01)`. The line angle equals: `(180/np.pi)*math.atan2(vy, vx)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use these opencv functions according to your needs

`fitEllipse()` , `fitEllipseAMS()`, `fitEllipseDirect()`

basically the function needs an array of points (your contour) and returns values . One of these values is the `orientation` of the contour.

https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaf259efaad93098103d6c27b9e4900ffa